# How do I get behind the wall in the far north while on a mission?

Tags: cyber-knights

Everytime I get a mission to the far north sectors, I end up being unable to complete it as the stupid taxi driver refuses to take me there when I'm on such a mission.  I can't seem to figure out how to walk there as the walls are in the way.  How do I get in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the only ways in are through Charles Bank and North End.  The main gate is at Charles Bank, but there are a few broken link fences over at North End that allows you to sneak past the wall.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter from both the east and the west.

From the west, walk into River Park (the far northwest sector) and then walk east.  You will be outside of the wall surrounding the West End, and can walk north of that wall to get into the Blue Ox area and get to the far north sectors.

Or you can start in the North End and walk around the very far northern edge of the wall and through the broken fences.